# Signal strength of wifi very weak

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless

It was the same in Ubuntu 14.04 so I updated my OS to 16.04 hoping that it will automatically get fixed. Issue wasn't resolved so i updated to Ubuntu 17.04 and the problem is still there. I have Windows installed on the other side which works fine.

Edit :

```
$ lspci -knn | grep -iA3 net 
07:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 07)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller [103c:80c1]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169
0d:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:b723]
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [103c:804c]
    Kernel driver in use: rtl8723be
    Kernel modules: rtl8723be
```

Comment: I added the output of the given command.

Comment: The best match is https://askubuntu.com/questions/883673/rtl8723be-wifi-incredibly-weak There is no need to install any drivers for the new kernels. We can reopen and close as a duplicate.

Comment: You're the best stack overflow. It took just 2 days to solve my problem. At some point i thought that my laptop was useless. @Pilot6 you solved my problem.