# Wifi not working on Ubuntu 16.04.02 on HP RTL8723BE

Tags: wireless

**I am able to see the WiFi connection**, but I am not able to connect to it.

```
$ iwconfig 
wlp2s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr=2347 B   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off

lo        no wireless extensions.

enp1s0    no wireless extensions.

enp0s20u1  no wireless extensions.
```

I updated my system using:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

then rebooted it, but nothing happened.

```
$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A3**
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:b723]
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [103c:804c]
    Kernel driver in use: rtl8723be
    Kernel modules: rtl8723be, wl
```

**update**

```
$ sudo lshw -C network
  *-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: enp1s0
       version: 07
       serial: 70:5a:0f:d3:46:d0
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8106e-1_0.0.1 06/29/12 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:43 ioport:4000(size=256) memory:c1200000-c1200fff memory:c1000000-c1003fff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlp2s0
       version: 00
       serial: 68:14:01:68:3e:67
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8723be driverversion=4.8.0-36-generic firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:17 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:c1100000-c1103fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 3
       logical name: enp0s20u1
       serial: d6:e5:75:79:38:fc
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rndis_host driverversion=22-Aug-2005 firmware=RNDIS device ip=192.168.42.209 link=yes multicast=yes
```

**UPDATE:** I got this error message related to wifi.How to solve this.
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oTNJX.png)

Can i purge this ?

```
$ locate rtlwifi-new-dkms
/home/maddy/.cache/upstart/update-notifier-crash-_var_crash_rtlwifi-new-dkms.0.crash.log.1.gz
/home/maddy/.cache/upstart/update-notifier-crash-_var_crash_rtlwifi-new-dkms.0.crash.log.2.gz
/home/maddy/.cache/upstart/update-notifier-crash-_var_crash_rtlwifi-new-dkms.0.crash.log.3.gz
/home/maddy/.cache/upstart/update-notifier-crash-_var_crash_rtlwifi-new-dkms.0.crash.log.4.gz
/home/maddy/.cache/upstart/update-notifier-crash-_var_crash_rtlwifi-new-dkms.0.crash.log.5.gz
/home/maddy/.cache/upstart/update-notifier-crash-_var_crash_rtlwifi-new-dkms.0.crash.log.6.gz
/home/maddy/.cache/upstart/update-notifier-crash-_var_crash_rtlwifi-new-dkms.0.crash.log.7.gz
/usr/share/rtlwifi-new-dkms
/usr/share/rtlwifi-new-dkms/postinst
/var/cache/apt/archives/rtlwifi-new-dkms_0.10_all.deb
/var/lib/dpkg/info/rtlwifi-new-dkms.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/rtlwifi-new-dkms.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/rtlwifi-new-dkms.postinst
/var/lib/dpkg/info/rtlwifi-new-dkms.prerm
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` terminal command.

Comment: @Pilot6 i updated my post , can you suggest something now.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rtl8723be WiFi incredibly weak](https://askubuntu.com/questions/883673/rtl8723be-wifi-incredibly-weak)

Comment: @Pilot6 I tried the  command you  mentioned on this link , still problem is not solved . It keep asking for the password after some trying to connect to wifi.

Comment: Did you try both `ant_sel=2` and 1? Did you reboot after the command? What is the kernel version `uname -a`?

Comment: yes i tried this * sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf <<< "options rtl8723be ant_sel=2"*

Comment: still problem same

Comment: Try `ant_sel=1`

Comment: @Pilot6 Sir initially I tried with ant_sel=1, it still shows available WiFi , I enter password , it keeps trying to connect, and finally ask for password again. I even deleted all the WiFi from edit connections, even then same issue. Can it be due to low signal strength

Comment: What do you mean by you're not able to connect to it, so you can see it and your password ain't working, perhaps your cap locks in on or you have the wrong password

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get a Realtek RTL8723BE wireless card to work?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/635625/how-do-i-get-a-realtek-rtl8723be-wireless-card-to-work)