# WiFi on a particular network not working

Tags: wireless

One particular WiFi network is not working on my Ubuntu 16.10 system. It connects to all other WiFI networks except a particular one.

And when it does connect sometimes, it does not have internet access (no webpage loads).

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 23 Jun 2017 16:10 IST +0530

Booted last: 23 Jun 2017 00:00 IST +0530

Script from: 25 Mar 2017 07:04 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.10
Release:    16.10
Codename:   yakkety

##### kernel ############################

Linux 4.8.0-22-generic #24-Ubuntu SMP Sat Oct 8 09:15:00 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7

##### desktop ###########################

Ubuntu

##### lspci #############################

01:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 07)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller [103c:81db]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169

02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:b723]
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [103c:81c1]
    Kernel driver in use: rtl8723be

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:b008 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 05c8:038f Cheng Uei Precision Industry Co., Ltd (Foxlink) 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

##### lsmod #############################

rtl8723be              90112  0
btcoexist              53248  1 rtl8723be
rtl8723_common         24576  1 rtl8723be
rtl_pci                28672  1 rtl8723be
rtlwifi                77824  2 rtl_pci,rtl8723be
mac80211              757760  3 rtl_pci,rtlwifi,rtl8723be
hp_wmi                 16384  0
sparse_keymap          16384  1 hp_wmi
cfg80211              581632  2 mac80211,rtlwifi
wmi                    16384  1 hp_wmi

##### interfaces ########################

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### ifconfig ##########################

enp1s0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether <MAC address>  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 159023  bytes 143525505 (143.5 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 149012  bytes 142593569 (142.5 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 28397  bytes 1834139 (1.8 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 28397  bytes 1834139 (1.8 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlp2s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.4  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::568c:a0ff:feab:c28d  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether <MAC address>  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 18587  bytes 15945088 (15.9 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 21306  bytes 12266615 (12.2 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

##### iwconfig ##########################

lo        no wireless extensions.

enp1s0    no wireless extensions.

wlp2s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"Linga Bhairavi"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.417 GHz  Access Point: <MAC 'Linga Bhairavi' [AC1]>   
          Bit Rate=72.2 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr=2347 B   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=32/70  Signal level=-78 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:47   Missed beacon:0

##### route #############################

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlp2s0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 wlp2s0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlp2s0

##### resolv.conf #######################

nameserver 127.0.1.1

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager

Running:

root       728     1  0 15:44 ?        00:00:02 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

##### NetworkManager info ###############

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         wlp2s0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           wifi
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceWifi
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         rtl8723be
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 4.8.0-22-generic
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               N/A
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC address>
GENERAL.MTU:                            0
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.5/0000:02:00.0/net/wlp2s0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       wlp2s0
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     Linga Bhairavi
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       4c8ae406-b324-49b4-946b-dea03c379a08
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/9
GENERAL.METERED:                        no (guessed)
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            no
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     72 Mb/s
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WEP:                    yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA:                    yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA2:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.TKIP:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.CCMP:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.AP:                     yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.ADHOC:                  yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.2GHZ:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.5GHZ:                   no
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/{2}
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   4c8ae406-b324-49b4-946b-dea03c379a08 | Linga Bhairavi
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         192.168.1.4/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            192.168.1.1
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 169.254.0.0/16, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 1000
IP4.DNS[1]:                             192.168.1.1
DHCP4.OPTION[1]:                        requested_routers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[2]:                        requested_domain_search = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[3]:                        requested_time_offset = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[4]:                        requested_domain_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[5]:                        requested_rfc3442_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[6]:                        requested_broadcast_address = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[7]:                        requested_netbios_scope = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[8]:                        requested_wpad = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[9]:                        next_server = 0.0.0.0
DHCP4.OPTION[10]:                       expiry = 1498300271
DHCP4.OPTION[11]:                       requested_interface_mtu = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[12]:                       requested_subnet_mask = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[13]:                       dhcp_lease_time = 86400
DHCP4.OPTION[14]:                       dhcp_message_type = 5
DHCP4.OPTION[15]:                       ip_address = 192.168.1.4
DHCP4.OPTION[16]:                       requested_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[17]:                       requested_domain_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[18]:                       routers = 192.168.1.1
DHCP4.OPTION[19]:                       broadcast_address = 192.168.1.255
DHCP4.OPTION[20]:                       requested_ntp_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[21]:                       requested_netbios_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[22]:                       domain_name_servers = 192.168.1.1
DHCP4.OPTION[23]:                       requested_ms_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[24]:                       subnet_mask = 255.255.255.0
DHCP4.OPTION[25]:                       network_number = 192.168.1.0
DHCP4.OPTION[26]:                       requested_host_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[27]:                       dhcp_server_identifier = 192.168.1.1
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fe80::568c:a0ff:feab:c28d/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         enp1s0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceEthernet
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         r8169
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 2.3LK-NAPI
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC address>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          20 (unavailable)
GENERAL.REASON:                         40 (Carrier/link changed)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.0/0000:01:00.0/net/enp1s0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
GENERAL.METERED:                        unknown
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     100 Mb/s
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               off
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: 

SSID            BSSID              MODE   CHAN  FREQ      RATE       SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY  ACTIVE  * 
Linga Bhairavi  <MAC 'Linga Bhairavi' [AC1]>  Infra  2     2417 MHz  54 Mbit/s  46      ▂▄__  WPA2      yes     * 

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager.conf ###############

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Ashmita]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Ashmita | type=wifi | permissions=user:cms:;
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC address> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=Ashmita
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Linga Bhairavi]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Linga Bhairavi | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC address> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=Linga Bhairavi
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=ignore

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/HPCLab]] (600 root)
[connection] id=HPCLab | type=wifi | permissions=user:cms:;
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC address> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=HPCLab
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: Asia/Kolkata (based on set time zone)

country 00: DFS-UNSET
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-OFDM, NO-IR
    (5170 - 5250 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
    (5250 - 5330 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, NO-IR
    (5490 - 5730 @ 160), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, NO-IR
    (5735 - 5835 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
    (57240 - 63720 @ 2160), (N/A, 0), (N/A)

##### iwlist channels ###################

lo        no frequency information.

enp1s0    no frequency information.

wlp2s0    13 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Channel 12 : 2.467 GHz
          Channel 13 : 2.472 GHz
          Current Frequency:2.417 GHz (Channel 2)

##### iwlist scan #######################

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

enp1s0    Interface doesn't support scanning.

Channel occupancy:

      1   APs on   Frequency:2.417 GHz (Channel 2)

wlp2s0    Scan completed :
          Cell 01 - Address: <MAC 'Linga Bhairavi' [AC1]>
                    Channel:2
                    Frequency:2.417 GHz (Channel 2)
                    Quality=28/70  Signal level=-82 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"Linga Bhairavi"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s
                              18 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000000023a1d9e6
                    Extra: Last beacon: 64ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK

##### module infos ######################

[rtl8723be]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.8.0-22-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtlwifi/rtl8723be/rtl8723be.ko
firmware:       rtlwifi/rtl8723befw.bin
description:    Realtek 8723BE 802.11n PCI wireless
license:        GPL
author:         Realtek WlanFAE <wlanfae@realtek.com>
author:         PageHe  <page_he@realsil.com.cn>
srcversion:     1520FD8B69687790125304A
depends:        rtlwifi,rtl8723-common,rtl_pci,btcoexist,mac80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.8.0-22-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           swenc:Set to 1 for software crypto (default 0)
 (bool)
parm:           ips:Set to 0 to not use link power save (default 1)
 (bool)
parm:           swlps:Set to 1 to use SW control power save (default 0)
 (bool)
parm:           fwlps:Set to 1 to use FW control power save (default 1)
 (bool)
parm:           msi:Set to 1 to use MSI interrupts mode (default 0)
 (bool)
parm:           debug:Set debug level (0-5) (default 0) (int)
parm:           disable_watchdog:Set to 1 to disable the watchdog (default 0)
 (bool)
parm:           ant_sel:Set to 1 or 2 to force antenna number (default 0)
 (int)

[rtl8723_common]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.8.0-22-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtlwifi/rtl8723com/rtl8723-common.ko
description:    Realtek RTL8723AE/RTL8723BE 802.11n PCI wireless common routines
license:        GPL
author:         Larry Finger    <Larry.Finger@lwfinger.net>
author:         Realtek WlanFAE <wlanfae@realtek.com>
srcversion:     B06F4AE01E9561133D82E7E
depends:        
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.8.0-22-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 

[rtl_pci]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.8.0-22-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtlwifi/rtl_pci.ko
description:    PCI basic driver for rtlwifi
license:        GPL
author:         Larry Finger    <Larry.FInger@lwfinger.net>
author:         Realtek WlanFAE <wlanfae@realtek.com>
author:         lizhaoming  <chaoming_li@realsil.com.cn>
srcversion:     7AD0477B303BCC50CCDBB66
depends:        mac80211,rtlwifi
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.8.0-22-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 

[rtlwifi]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.8.0-22-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtlwifi/rtlwifi.ko
description:    Realtek 802.11n PCI wireless core
license:        GPL
author:         Larry Finger    <Larry.FInger@lwfinger.net>
author:         Realtek WlanFAE <wlanfae@realtek.com>
author:         lizhaoming  <chaoming_li@realsil.com.cn>
srcversion:     6A6725975155C4D9E514CE1
depends:        mac80211,cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.8.0-22-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 

[mac80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.8.0-22-generic/kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko
license:        GPL
description:    IEEE 802.11 subsystem
srcversion:     BDE5CB0CC0A980B65D19934
depends:        cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.8.0-22-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           minstrel_vht_only:Use only VHT rates when VHT is supported by sta. (bool)
parm:           max_nullfunc_tries:Maximum nullfunc tx tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           max_probe_tries:Maximum probe tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           beacon_loss_count:Number of beacon intervals before we decide beacon was lost. (int)
parm:           probe_wait_ms:Maximum time(ms) to wait for probe response before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           ieee80211_default_rc_algo:Default rate control algorithm for mac80211 to use (charp)

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.8.0-22-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
author:         Johannes Berg
srcversion:     F170FED576AF12B070D2E69
depends:        
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.8.0-22-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

##### module parameters #################

[rtl8723be]
ant_sel: 0
debug: 0
disable_watchdog: N
fwlps: Y
ips: Y
msi: N
swenc: N
swlps: N

[mac80211]
beacon_loss_count: 7
ieee80211_default_rc_algo: minstrel_ht
max_nullfunc_tries: 2
max_probe_tries: 5
minstrel_vht_only: Y
probe_wait_ms: 500

[cfg80211]
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

##### /etc/modules ######################

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/intel-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

[/etc/modprobe.d/mlx4.conf]
softdep mlx4_core post: mlx4_en

##### rc.local ##########################

grep: /etc/rc.local: No such file or directory

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

##### dmesg #############################

[  309.402393] wlp2s0: Connection to AP <MAC 'Linga Bhairavi' [AC1]> lost
[  323.321492] wlp2s0: authenticate with <MAC 'Linga Bhairavi' [AC1]>
[  323.342872] wlp2s0: send auth to <MAC 'Linga Bhairavi' [AC1]> (try 1/3)
[  323.349526] wlp2s0: authenticated
[  323.349656] wlp2s0: associating with AP with corrupt probe response
[  323.355235] wlp2s0: associate with <MAC 'Linga Bhairavi' [AC1]> (try 1/3)
[  323.364692] wlp2s0: RX AssocResp from <MAC 'Linga Bhairavi' [AC1]> (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=4)
[  323.365482] wlp2s0: associated
[  325.143258] wlp2s0: deauthenticating from <MAC 'Linga Bhairavi' [AC1]> by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
[  326.121430] wlp2s0: authenticate with <MAC 'Linga Bhairavi' [AC1]>
[  326.145679] wlp2s0: send auth to <MAC 'Linga Bhairavi' [AC1]> (try 1/3)
[  326.247341] wlp2s0: send auth to <MAC 'Linga Bhairavi' [AC1]> (try 2/3)
[  326.252132] wlp2s0: authenticated
[  326.252610] wlp2s0: associating with AP with corrupt probe response
[  326.255397] wlp2s0: associate with <MAC 'Linga Bhairavi' [AC1]> (try 1/3)
[  326.265532] wlp2s0: RX AssocResp from <MAC 'Linga Bhairavi' [AC1]> (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=4)
[  326.267018] wlp2s0: associated
[  344.532573] wlp2s0: Connection to AP <MAC 'Linga Bhairavi' [AC1]> lost
[  360.127341] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp2s0: link is not ready
[  362.620445] wlp2s0: authenticate with <MAC 'Linga Bhairavi' [AC1]>
[  362.635575] wlp2s0: send auth to <MAC 'Linga Bhairavi' [AC1]> (try 1/3)
[  362.740157] wlp2s0: send auth to <MAC 'Linga Bhairavi' [AC1]> (try 2/3)
[  362.844104] wlp2s0: send auth to <MAC 'Linga Bhairavi' [AC1]> (try 3/3)
[  362.948064] wlp2s0: authentication with <MAC 'Linga Bhairavi' [AC1]> timed out
[  376.354340] wlp2s0: authenticate with <MAC 'Linga Bhairavi' [AC1]>
[  376.377760] wlp2s0: send auth to <MAC 'Linga Bhairavi' [AC1]> (try 1/3)
[  376.382366] wlp2s0: authenticated
[  376.382897] wlp2s0: associating with AP with corrupt probe response
[  376.384583] wlp2s0: associate with <MAC 'Linga Bhairavi' [AC1]> (try 1/3)
[  376.393444] wlp2s0: RX AssocResp from <MAC 'Linga Bhairavi' [AC1]> (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=4)
[  376.394031] wlp2s0: associated
[  376.394047] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp2s0: link becomes ready
[  594.016399] wlp2s0: deauthenticating from <MAC 'Linga Bhairavi' [AC1]> by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
[ 1016.725153] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp2s0: link is not ready
[ 1018.618729] wlp2s0: authenticate with <MAC 'Linga Bhairavi' [AC1]>
[ 1018.643201] wlp2s0: send auth to <MAC 'Linga Bhairavi' [AC1]> (try 1/3)
[ 1018.647963] wlp2s0: authenticated
[ 1018.648152] wlp2s0: associating with AP with corrupt probe response
[ 1018.649095] wlp2s0: associate with <MAC 'Linga Bhairavi' [AC1]> (try 1/3)
[ 1018.656799] wlp2s0: RX AssocResp from <MAC 'Linga Bhairavi' [AC1]> (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=3)
[ 1018.659271] wlp2s0: associated
[ 1018.659288] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp2s0: link becomes ready

########## wireless info END ############
```

Comment: Thank you. I have edited the question to include the same.

Comment: Could you please try the answers to “[How do I get a Realtek RTL8723BE wireless card to work?](/q/635625/175814)”? You can also look at [other questions dealing with the RTL8723BE chipset](/search?tab=votes&q=RTL8723BE). Thanks.

Comment: Which one is that particular SSID? It looks like the signal is low. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/883673/rtl8723be-wifi-incredibly-weak

Comment: It works perfectly now after i set the ant_sel=1. Thank you.