# WIFI: Unable to connect to DLink router

Tags: wireless

```
**vishwa@vishwa-HP-Notebook:~$ dmesg**
[  474.601906] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp19s0: link is not ready
[  483.258050] wlp19s0: authenticate with ec:22:80:86:88:58
[  483.281336] wlp19s0: send auth to ec:22:80:86:88:58 (try 1/3)
[  483.384450] wlp19s0: send auth to ec:22:80:86:88:58 (try 2/3)
[  483.488419] wlp19s0: send auth to ec:22:80:86:88:58 (try 3/3)
[  483.592520] wlp19s0: authentication with ec:22:80:86:88:58 timed out



**rfkill list** 
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

**iwlist wlp19s0 scan**
wlp19s0   Scan completed :
          Cell 01 - Address: EC:22:80:86:88:58
                    Channel:1
                    Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                    Quality=38/70  Signal level=-72 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"NAMENAME"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                              9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=00000002ef4cd173
                    Extra: Last beacon: 29096ms ago
                    IE: Unknown: 000F4F6D4E616D6F56656E6B6174657368
                    IE: Unknown: 010882848B960C121824
                    IE: Unknown: 030101
                    IE: Unknown: 050400010000
                    IE: Unknown: 2A0104
                    IE: Unknown: 32043048606C
                    IE: Unknown: 2D1A6E181EFF00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: 3D1601050000000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: 4A0E14000A00B400C800140005001900
                    IE: Unknown: 7F0101
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: Unknown: DD180050F2020101000003A4000027A4000042435E0062322F00
                    IE: Unknown: DD1E00904C336E181EFF00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: DD1A00904C3401050000000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: DD0600E04C020160
                    IE: Unknown: DD180050F204104A00011010440001021049000600372A000120


**lspci -v**

13:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    I/O ports at 3000 [size=256]
    Memory at d3000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: rtl8723be
    Kernel modules: rtl8723be
```

Comment: What is the Ubuntu version?

Comment: ubunutu version 16.04

Comment: If you are using kernel 4.8+, you need only to set the `ant_sel` parameter.

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/a/883688/167850

Answer (score 0):

Correct setting ant_sel parameter to 1 as below worked,

```
echo "options rtl8723be ant_sel=1"  | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf
```

Comment: I guess ant_sel value depends on WIFI hardware , ant_sel=2 didn't work for me.

Comment: It depends on  to which outlet the antenna is attached.

Comment: You will also have much better luck with WPA2-AES and not TKIP.