# Frequently network down even after being conneted to WIFI

Tags: wireless

I have to restart my network-manger once in an hour(random time) to get internet working, even after having  good wifi signal all of sudden network is down.

Environment
Ubuntu 16.04 and realtek wifi adapter.

```
**rfkill list**
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

**lspci -knn | grep "net" -A3**
07:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 07)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller [103c:80c1]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169
0d:00.0 Display controller [0380]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Sun XT [Radeon HD 8670A/8670M/8690M / R5 M330] [1002:6660] (rev 83)
```

***lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list***

```
13:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:b723]
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [103c:804c]
    Kernel driver in use: rtl8723be
    Kernel modules: rtl8723be
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: Is it a USB adapter? Then post the `lsusb` output.

Comment: It is not USB adapter, if i restart network-manger it works fine

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: I have added it

Answer (score 0):

You can fix it by upgrading the kernel to 4.10.

Run

```
sudo apt install linux-generic-hwe-16.04
```

and reboot.

Comment: I get following on trying that ,linux-generic-hwe-16.04 is already the newest version (4.10.0.37.39).  uname -a
Linux vishwa-HP-Notebook 4.10.0-37-generic #41~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Oct 6 22:42:59 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: Then it should work OK,  unless there is 1 antenna and a wrong one selected.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/946503/wifi-unable-to-connect-to-dlink-router   , earlier wifi was not working . It only worked for me after choosing write antenna