# wifi problem ubuntu 18.0.4 in hp ay03tx laptop tried every possible solution

Tags: 16.04, wireless, lubuntu

i am using hp ay503tx there is A problem with my wifi , wifi is detecting the networks but not all available neworks . and couldn't connect with them

my network detail is

```
 *-network
            description: Wireless interface
            product: RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
            vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
            physical id: 0
            bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
            logical name: wlo1
            version: 00
            serial: 3c:a0:67:76:a9:b5
            width: 64 bits
            clock: 33MHz
            capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
            configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8723be driverversion=4.10.0-33-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.43.165 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
            resources: irq:17 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:b1100000-b1103fff
```

Comment: did you try the lwfinger drivers? https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new

Comment: This post helped me: https://askubuntu.com/a/883688/3940

Comment: i have downloaded the file could help me with installation, when i unzip it and move inside it and open termilnal and type sudo make install it says  `make -C /lib/modules/4.10.0-33-generic/build M=/home/rizwan/Downloads/rtlwifi_new-master modules
make[1]: *** /lib/modules/4.10.0-33-generic/build: No such file or directory.  Stop.
Makefile:58: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
`

Answer (score 0):

It same wifi card's chip with mine (RTL8723BE)..
first open your terminal and type :

```
sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf
```

and then copy this code :

```
options rtl8723be ant_sel=1
```

and then press ctrl+x, choose 'Y' and then hit [enter]
now type again the command on your terminal :

```
sudo modprobe -rv rtl8723be
```

wait until finish and type again this code :

```
sudo modprobe -v rtl8723be
```

and try the wifi to connect to the Access point.

if it doesn't work, try again step by step but change this code:
from :

```
options rtl8723be ant_sel=1
```

to

```
options rtl8723be ant_sel=2
```

or

```
options rtl8723be ant_sel=0
```

it's work for me, I hope t will work for yout too,,,