# Wifi keeps disconnecting on Asus x541U running Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: wireless, asus

This problem only started occurring after I did a fresh install of Ubuntu 17.04. Whenever I restart, the internet works, for like 15 minutes at most, and then the internet will disconnect, and sometimes, reconnect. It will say connection established, but it won't always load sites after "reconnecting". There are multiple issues I am looking at here but they have the same source: Wifi cutting off randomly. I do use PIA VPN but even without the VPN, I seem to be encountering this issue. Anybody know how to proceed?

The device is Asus x541U, I have googled, none of the fixes work or are relevant to my device

As per request:

lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list

```
:~$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:b723]
    Subsystem: Lite-On Communications Inc RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [11ad:1723]
    Kernel driver in use: rtl8723be
    Kernel modules: rtl8723be
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

I have already tried this: [Rtl8723be WiFi incredibly weak](https://askubuntu.com/questions/883673/rtl8723be-wifi-incredibly-weak)

That query was about a weak signal, I am getting absolutely no connection at all now, after having followed the instructions there.

Comment: I've had the same problem once. It kept disconnecting for some reason.  I just reinstalled Ubuntu and it worked fine for me after that. I believe I had this problem when I was using 14.04 which isn't supported anymore. I have no idea. I would do a fresh install but there are probably other ways to solve this I just don't know them. Wait for others to respond and try their recommendations first before doing a fresh install. Or search the forums to see if you can get an answer.

Comment: The problem is that I *just* did a fresh install like, a few weeks ago.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: I just added it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rtl8723be WiFi incredibly weak](https://askubuntu.com/questions/883673/rtl8723be-wifi-incredibly-weak)

Comment: Tried the instructions on that. Now the Wi-Fi doesn't work at all

Comment: Tried ant_sel=2 and it is working now, so far. If it runs stable for an hour or so then that'll be great.

Comment: Nope. After restarting no connections show up, and in a way now it's worse

Answer (score 0):

I am experiencing the identical problem using ubuntu 17.04. I am using a Gigabyte GA-H97N-Wifi motherboard. This has been going on for several months, approximately since the time I started using the "802.11n" network in my home.

I attempted the following fixes:

```
nmcli nm enable false; sleep 0.5; nmcli nm enable true
# Fails, as "nm" is not a recognized option of nmcli
sudo service network-manager restart
# No change in status
sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager
# No change in status
rfkill block wifi; sleep 3 rfkill unlbock wifi
# No change in status
```

I have attempted to downgrade the connection from 802.11n, on start-up:

```
sudo modprobe iwlwifi 11n_disable=1
```

This may delay the failure; but a failure in wifi always comes eventually.

When I use "iwconfig" to check the status of wlan0, I note that sometimes "Tx excessive retries" goes from "0" to "1" simultaneous with the failure of the Wifi (checking every 2 minutes).  However, this does not occur 100% of the time; I would say about 90% of the time.

Finally: I note there was an update, which I installed 30 minutes ago (Oct 3 2017), and the wifi has operated fine for the past 30 minutes, which might be a several-month-long record!  EDIT: It didn't help!