# HP 15 BS576tx Laptop - Wifi not working

Tags: 16.04, hp

I am using HP 15 BS576tx laptop, but while I am installing Ubuntu 16.04 the Wi-Fi is not working.

Comment: The answer to this question did help me: https://askubuntu.com/questions/883673/rtl8723be-wifi-incredibly-weak

Comment: Also possibly related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/635625/how-do-i-get-a-realtek-rtl8723be-wireless-card-to-work (what is your Wifi card?)

Comment: its not working.

Comment: my wifi card  is Realtek RTL8723DE 802.11b/g/n

Comment: lspci -knn | grep Net -A3  command get result      |  03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:d723]
 DeviceName: Hanksville Gbe Lan Connection
 Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:8319]
 Kernel modules: ndiswrapper

Answer (score 0):

Nishadey...RTL8723DE is the wireless module used in HP 15-BS576TX and many other HP 15-BS00X Models. The driver is awaited in rtlwifi project by this month or January 2018. I myself have this laptop purchased on October 2017. https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Wireless-and-Networking/HP-bs576tx-wifi-card-not-detected-in-Ubuntu-16-04/m-p/6355584/highlight/true#M142283