# Ubuntu 17.10 Wireless/Wired Internet Connection Not Working on HP Notebook

Tags: networking, internet, 17.10

I have an HP laptop with these specs:

```
System Information
        Manufacturer: HP
        Product Name: HP Notebook
        Version: Type1ProductConfigId
        Family: 103C_5335KV G=N L=CON B=H
```

And I just installed Ubuntu 17.10 but the internet isn't working, either wireless or wired. Also, I have the following network specs:

```
hira@palebluedot:~$ sudo lshw -C network
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: enp2s0
       version: 07
       serial: fc:3f:db:5e:ff:35
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8106e-1_0.0.1 06/29/12 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:123 ioport:4000(size=256) memory:a1200000-a1200fff memory:a1000000-a1003fff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlp3s0
       version: 00
       serial: a8:a7:95:65:06:a7
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8723be driverversion=4.13.0-21-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.43.242 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:17 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:a1100000-a1103fff
```

Interestingly, the only internet that is working is a hotspot created via my cellular connection. The Wifi connection is sometimes not recognized (i.e it does not appear in the list of networks), sometimes recognized and connected but excruciatingly slow, and sometimes, recognized but not connected at all. Could anyone please help with this? I've tried upgrading my system as some solutions suggested but that isn't working. Also, note that it may not be a Ubuntu 17.10 problem because I was having the same issue with Ubuntu 16.04.3 and other Debian-derived versions (Linux Mint). Could anyone please help me with this?

Comment: The sanest thing is usually the ethernet cable, before you try anything wifi. Plug it in. Does the network manager tell you anything? What about `ifconfig`, does it list an eth* with defined ip4v address? If so, what do you get from `route -n`?

Comment: @Harald Thanks for the response! I just found the solution over [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/883673/rtl8723be-wifi-incredibly-weak). Apparently, the Linux drivers cannot detect which particular antenna my RTL8723be Wireless Adapter is using.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else experiencing the same issue, I found the solution over here:

[Rtl8723be WiFi incredibly weak](https://askubuntu.com/questions/883673/rtl8723be-wifi-incredibly-weak)