# Unstable wifi connection - "activation of network connection failed" Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager

I have installed Ubuntu 18.04 on my HP laptop. LAN cable works fine, but WIFI connection is terrible. It might work sometimes but starts weakening too soon - starts "connecting" and eventually says "activation of network connection failed".

I understand that this question is a duplicate, but have noticed that a lot of similar questions were either unanswered in the askubuntu portal or not helpful in my case. Spent hours to fix it but no result. Perhaps, this question will provide more relevant details to solve the problem.

Your help will be very appreciated.

Here is my wireless info retrieved from github wireless info script (or you can check it on [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/DQH0FHTg)):

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 12 May 2018 15:38 +04 +0400

Booted last: 12 May 2018 00:00 +04 +0400

Script from: 10 Jan 2018 20:04 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic

##### kernel ############################

Linux 4.15.0-20-generic #21-Ubuntu SMP Tue Apr 24 06:16:15 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=1

##### desktop ###########################

Ubuntu

##### lspci #############################

02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:b723]
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [103c:81c1]
    Kernel driver in use: rtl8723be

03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 15)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [103c:832d]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:b008 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:58ed Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 05e3:0608 Genesys Logic, Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0458:0186 KYE Systems Corp. (Mouse Systems) 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

##### lsmod #############################

rtl8723be              98304  0
btcoexist             131072  1 rtl8723be
rtl8723_common         24576  1 rtl8723be
rtl_pci                32768  1 rtl8723be
rtlwifi                77824  4 rtl_pci,btcoexist,rtl8723_common,rtl8723be
mac80211              778240  3 rtl_pci,rtlwifi,rtl8723be
cfg80211              622592  2 mac80211,rtlwifi
hp_wmi                 16384  0
wmi_bmof               16384  0
sparse_keymap          16384  1 hp_wmi
wmi                    24576  2 wmi_bmof,hp_wmi

##### interfaces ########################

[/etc/network/interfaces]
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### ifconfig ##########################

eno1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.7  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::c4df:c01d:67a9:e172  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether <MAC address>  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 101603  bytes 120654085 (120.6 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 72693  bytes 8859205 (8.8 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 7789  bytes 682238 (682.2 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 7789  bytes 682238 (682.2 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlo1: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether <MAC address>  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 82418  bytes 100958947 (100.9 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 50621  bytes 5415199 (5.4 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

##### iwconfig ##########################

eno1      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlo1      IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr=2347 B   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on


##### route #############################

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eno1
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 eno1
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 eno1

##### resolv.conf #######################

nameserver 127.0.0.53

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager
    Wicd

Running:

root      1016     1  0 14:29 ?        00:00:04 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

##### NetworkManager info ###############

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         eno1
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceEthernet
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         r8169
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 2.3LK-NAPI
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               --
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC address>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.3/0000:03:00.0/net/eno1
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       eno1
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     Wired connection 1
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       444d0395-a533-3a4a-9c78-6833a0f09397
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/16
GENERAL.METERED:                        no (guessed)
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     100 Mb/s
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
CAPABILITIES.SRIOV:                     no
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               on
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         192.168.1.7/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            192.168.1.1
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 0.0.0.0/0, nh = 192.168.1.1, mt = 100
IP4.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = 192.168.1.0/24, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 100
IP4.ROUTE[3]:                           dst = 169.254.0.0/16, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 1000
IP4.DNS[1]:                             77.74.44.44
IP4.DNS[2]:                             212.58.96.96
IP4.DNS[3]:                             8.8.8.8
IP4.DNS[4]:                             192.168.1.1
DHCP4.OPTION[1]:                        requested_host_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[2]:                        requested_domain_search = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[3]:                        requested_time_offset = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[4]:                        requested_broadcast_address = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[5]:                        requested_rfc3442_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[6]:                        requested_domain_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[7]:                        requested_wpad = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[8]:                        requested_netbios_scope = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[9]:                        next_server = 0.0.0.0
DHCP4.OPTION[10]:                       broadcast_address = 192.168.1.255
DHCP4.OPTION[11]:                       dhcp_message_type = 5
DHCP4.OPTION[12]:                       requested_interface_mtu = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[13]:                       routers = 192.168.1.1
DHCP4.OPTION[14]:                       dhcp_lease_time = 7200
DHCP4.OPTION[15]:                       ip_address = 192.168.1.7
DHCP4.OPTION[16]:                       requested_domain_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[17]:                       subnet_mask = 255.255.255.0
DHCP4.OPTION[18]:                       requested_subnet_mask = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[19]:                       requested_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[20]:                       expiry = 1526131586
DHCP4.OPTION[21]:                       domain_name_servers = 77.74.44.44 212.58.96.96 8.8.8.8 192.168.1.1
DHCP4.OPTION[22]:                       requested_ntp_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[23]:                       requested_netbios_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[24]:                       requested_routers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[25]:                       requested_ms_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[26]:                       network_number = 192.168.1.0
DHCP4.OPTION[27]:                       dhcp_server_identifier = 192.168.1.1
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fe80::c4df:c01d:67a9:e172/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            --
IP6.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = ff00::/8, nh = ::, mt = 256, table=255
IP6.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = fe80::/64, nh = ::, mt = 256
IP6.ROUTE[3]:                           dst = fe80::/64, nh = ::, mt = 100
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/{2}
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   444d0395-a533-3a4a-9c78-6833a0f09397 | Wired connection 1

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         wlo1
GENERAL.TYPE:                           wifi
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceWifi
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         rtl8723be
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 4.15.0-20-generic
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               N/A
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC address>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          30 (disconnected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.2/0000:02:00.0/net/wlo1
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       --
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
GENERAL.METERED:                        unknown
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            no
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
CAPABILITIES.SRIOV:                     no
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WEP:                    yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA:                    yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA2:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.TKIP:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.CCMP:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.AP:                     yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.ADHOC:                  yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.2GHZ:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.5GHZ:                   no
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/{3}
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   76aa10c5-326c-4ce3-bd75-f34fd2002acb | VKN

SSID  BSSID              MODE   CHAN  FREQ      RATE        SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY   ACTIVE  IN-USE 
VKN   <MAC 'VKN' [AC1]>  Infra  1     2412 MHz  135 Mbit/s  90      ▂▄▆█  WPA1 WPA2  no             

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager.conf ###############

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile

[ifupdown]
managed=false

[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/VKN]] (600 root)
[connection] id=VKN | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC address> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=VKN
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

##### Netplan config ####################

[/etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml]
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: Asia/Tbilisi (based on set time zone)

global
country 00: DFS-UNSET
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 20), (N/A, 20), (N/A), AUTO-BW, NO-IR
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-OFDM, NO-IR
    (5170 - 5250 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), AUTO-BW, NO-IR
    (5250 - 5330 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, AUTO-BW, NO-IR
    (5490 - 5730 @ 160), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, NO-IR
    (5735 - 5835 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
    (57240 - 63720 @ 2160), (N/A, 0), (N/A)

##### iwlist channels ###################

eno1      no frequency information.

lo        no frequency information.

wlo1      13 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Channel 12 : 2.467 GHz
          Channel 13 : 2.472 GHz

##### iwlist scan #######################

eno1      Interface doesn't support scanning.

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

Channel occupancy:

      1   APs on   Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)

wlo1      Scan completed :
          Cell 01 - Address: <MAC 'VKN' [AC1]>
                    Channel:1
                    Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                    Quality=64/70  Signal level=-46 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"VKN"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                              9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=00000050ee8ec472
                    Extra: Last beacon: 300ms ago
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : TKIP CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : TKIP CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK

##### module infos ######################

[rtl8723be]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.15.0-20-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtlwifi/rtl8723be/rtl8723be.ko
firmware:       rtlwifi/rtl8723befw_36.bin
firmware:       rtlwifi/rtl8723befw.bin
description:    Realtek 8723BE 802.11n PCI wireless
license:        GPL
author:         Realtek WlanFAE <wlanfae@realtek.com>
author:         PageHe  <page_he@realsil.com.cn>
srcversion:     6A56582B1FEECB841E329C4
depends:        rtlwifi,rtl8723-common,rtl_pci,btcoexist,mac80211
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           rtl8723be
vermagic:       4.15.0-20-generic SMP mod_unload 
signat:         PKCS#7
signer:         
sig_key:        
sig_hashalgo:   md4
parm:           swenc:Set to 1 for software crypto (default 0)
 (bool)
parm:           ips:Set to 0 to not use link power save (default 1)
 (bool)
parm:           swlps:Set to 1 to use SW control power save (default 0)
 (bool)
parm:           fwlps:Set to 1 to use FW control power save (default 1)
 (bool)
parm:           msi:Set to 1 to use MSI interrupts mode (default 0)
 (bool)
parm:           aspm:Set to 1 to enable ASPM (default 1)
 (int)
parm:           debug_level:Set debug level (0-5) (default 0) (int)
parm:           debug_mask:Set debug mask (default 0) (ullong)
parm:           disable_watchdog:Set to 1 to disable the watchdog (default 0)
 (bool)
parm:           ant_sel:Set to 1 or 2 to force antenna number (default 0)
 (int)

[rtl8723_common]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.15.0-20-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtlwifi/rtl8723com/rtl8723-common.ko
description:    Realtek RTL8723AE/RTL8723BE 802.11n PCI wireless common routines
license:        GPL
author:         Larry Finger    <Larry.Finger@lwfinger.net>
author:         Realtek WlanFAE <wlanfae@realtek.com>
srcversion:     90DB9C652E26F4135F339B8
depends:        rtlwifi
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           rtl8723_common
vermagic:       4.15.0-20-generic SMP mod_unload 
signat:         PKCS#7
signer:         
sig_key:        
sig_hashalgo:   md4

[rtl_pci]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.15.0-20-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtlwifi/rtl_pci.ko
description:    PCI basic driver for rtlwifi
license:        GPL
author:         Larry Finger    <Larry.FInger@lwfinger.net>
author:         Realtek WlanFAE <wlanfae@realtek.com>
author:         lizhaoming  <chaoming_li@realsil.com.cn>
srcversion:     9F5FA8A771710F4CA500C6E
depends:        mac80211,rtlwifi
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           rtl_pci
vermagic:       4.15.0-20-generic SMP mod_unload 
signat:         PKCS#7
signer:         
sig_key:        
sig_hashalgo:   md4

[rtlwifi]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.15.0-20-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtlwifi/rtlwifi.ko
description:    Realtek 802.11n PCI wireless core
license:        GPL
author:         Larry Finger    <Larry.FInger@lwfinger.net>
author:         Realtek WlanFAE <wlanfae@realtek.com>
author:         lizhaoming  <chaoming_li@realsil.com.cn>
srcversion:     8AB8B2AAF3BCFFB93D91956
depends:        mac80211,cfg80211
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           rtlwifi
vermagic:       4.15.0-20-generic SMP mod_unload 
signat:         PKCS#7
signer:         
sig_key:        
sig_hashalgo:   md4

[mac80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.15.0-20-generic/kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko
license:        GPL
description:    IEEE 802.11 subsystem
srcversion:     1CEA5CF286EDB289C1D0BF8
depends:        cfg80211
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           mac80211
vermagic:       4.15.0-20-generic SMP mod_unload 
signat:         PKCS#7
signer:         
sig_key:        
sig_hashalgo:   md4
parm:           minstrel_vht_only:Use only VHT rates when VHT is supported by sta. (bool)
parm:           max_nullfunc_tries:Maximum nullfunc tx tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           max_probe_tries:Maximum probe tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           beacon_loss_count:Number of beacon intervals before we decide beacon was lost. (int)
parm:           probe_wait_ms:Maximum time(ms) to wait for probe response before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           ieee80211_default_rc_algo:Default rate control algorithm for mac80211 to use (charp)

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.15.0-20-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
author:         Johannes Berg
srcversion:     D5B0789D4C423C81CCFB437
depends:        
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           cfg80211
vermagic:       4.15.0-20-generic SMP mod_unload 
signat:         PKCS#7
signer:         
sig_key:        
sig_hashalgo:   md4
parm:           bss_entries_limit:limit to number of scan BSS entries (per wiphy, default 1000) (int)
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

##### module parameters #################

[rtl8723be]
ant_sel: 1
aspm: 1
debug_level: 0
debug_mask: 0
disable_watchdog: N
fwlps: Y
ips: Y
msi: N
swenc: N
swlps: N

[mac80211]
beacon_loss_count: 7
ieee80211_default_rc_algo: minstrel_ht
max_nullfunc_tries: 2
max_probe_tries: 5
minstrel_vht_only: Y
probe_wait_ms: 500

[cfg80211]
bss_entries_limit: 1000
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

##### /etc/modules ######################

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

[/etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf]
options rtl8723be ant_sel=1

##### rc.local ##########################

grep: /etc/rc.local: No such file or directory

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

##### dmesg #############################

[ 2829.176333] wlo1: authenticate with <MAC 'VKN' [AC1]>
[ 2829.195118] wlo1: send auth to <MAC 'VKN' [AC1]> (try 1/3)
[ 2829.298125] wlo1: send auth to <MAC 'VKN' [AC1]> (try 2/3)
[ 2829.402028] wlo1: send auth to <MAC 'VKN' [AC1]> (try 3/3)
[ 2829.506116] wlo1: authentication with <MAC 'VKN' [AC1]> timed out
[ 2842.868646] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlo1: link is not ready
[ 2843.874669] wlo1: authenticate with <MAC 'VKN' [AC1]>
[ 2843.884909] wlo1: send auth to <MAC 'VKN' [AC1]> (try 1/3)
[ 2843.986126] wlo1: send auth to <MAC 'VKN' [AC1]> (try 2/3)
[ 2844.090128] wlo1: send auth to <MAC 'VKN' [AC1]> (try 3/3)
[ 2844.193857] wlo1: authentication with <MAC 'VKN' [AC1]> timed out
[ 2855.175916] wlo1: authenticate with <MAC 'VKN' [AC1]>
[ 2855.194590] wlo1: send auth to <MAC 'VKN' [AC1]> (try 1/3)
[ 2855.297870] wlo1: send auth to <MAC 'VKN' [AC1]> (try 2/3)
[ 2855.402048] wlo1: send auth to <MAC 'VKN' [AC1]> (try 3/3)
[ 2855.505819] wlo1: authentication with <MAC 'VKN' [AC1]> timed out
[ 2868.862717] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlo1: link is not ready
[ 2886.625475] wlo1: authenticate with <MAC 'VKN' [AC1]>
[ 2886.635699] wlo1: send auth to <MAC 'VKN' [AC1]> (try 1/3)
[ 2886.737261] wlo1: send auth to <MAC 'VKN' [AC1]> (try 2/3)
[ 2886.841218] wlo1: send auth to <MAC 'VKN' [AC1]> (try 3/3)
[ 2886.944929] wlo1: authentication with <MAC 'VKN' [AC1]> timed out
[ 2897.920459] wlo1: authenticate with <MAC 'VKN' [AC1]>
[ 2897.937774] wlo1: send auth to <MAC 'VKN' [AC1]> (try 1/3)
[ 2898.041047] wlo1: send auth to <MAC 'VKN' [AC1]> (try 2/3)
[ 2898.144876] wlo1: send auth to <MAC 'VKN' [AC1]> (try 3/3)
[ 2898.248856] wlo1: authentication with <MAC 'VKN' [AC1]> timed out
[ 2911.871814] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlo1: link is not ready
[ 3171.165435] wlo1: authenticate with <MAC 'VKN' [AC1]>
[ 3171.185028] wlo1: send auth to <MAC 'VKN' [AC1]> (try 1/3)
[ 3171.186810] wlo1: authenticated
[ 3171.188539] wlo1: associate with <MAC 'VKN' [AC1]> (try 1/3)
[ 3171.194032] wlo1: RX AssocResp from <MAC 'VKN' [AC1]> (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=3)
[ 3171.194279] wlo1: associated
[ 3171.265751] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlo1: link becomes ready
[ 3428.602225] wlo1: deauthenticating from <MAC 'VKN' [AC1]> by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
[ 3432.199904] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlo1: link is not ready (repeated 5 times)

########## wireless info END ############
```

Comment: Please see: https://askubuntu.com/questions/635625/how-do-i-get-a-realtek-rtl8723be-wireless-card-to-work You probably only need the ant-sel parameter. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @chili555 I went trough the commands, and this one not worked: `sudo apt-get install rtlwifi-new-dkms`  it said: "E: Unable to locate package rtlwifi-new-dkms".  I executed next one: `echo "options rtl8723be ant_sel=2"  | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf`, then rebooted and now signal is really strong. It worked. Thank you very much!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rtl8723be WiFi incredibly weak](https://askubuntu.com/questions/883673/rtl8723be-wifi-incredibly-weak) (cc @chili555)

Comment: @pomsky - previous comment has worked for me.

Comment: @Vakhtang The question I linked *specifically* deals with weak signal issue (check it, they are the same solution actually).

Comment: Thank you very much for such a quick and helpful answers!

Comment: I believe this issue has to do with connecting to a network using TKIP encryption as opposed to AES. Your solution worked perfectly for me, please post it as an answer and mark it as solved @Vakhtang