# Every kernel update needs wifi drivers reinstalled (RTL8723be)

Tags: networking, drivers, upgrade, kernel, rtl8723be

I am currently on ubuntu 20.04 and whenever I get kernel update I have to go through wifi driver [installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1058379/wifi-signal-is-weak-in-ubuntu-18-04-with-rtl8723be) again and again. I am tired of this and thinking of changing the OS(may try Pop!_OS) if I don't find any solution. So is there any permanent fx for this?

Comment: Pop!_Os probably will not solve your problem as it uses the same default drivers as ubuntu. Are you using dkms?

Comment: @Bruni yes. most probably. How to check that? I think fresh installation can solve my problem because earlier it was working fine with kernel update

Comment: Most probably you do not, as DKMS automatically recompiles all DKMS modules if a new kernel version is installed. All the answers given in the question you have linked to (excluding the question itself) do not provide the DKMS modules for the wifi driver. This means that you should either find a repository for the driver that also includes those or indeed having to update the driver manually, if the default driver does not meet your needs. This https://askubuntu.com/questions/408605/what-does-dkms-do-how-do-i-use-it might help you, though I have not tried it.