# Wifi strength extremely weak in ubuntu 18.04.1 with RTL8723BE

Tags: wireless, 18.04, hp, realtek-wireless

I have hp 15-ac122tu laptop. I've installed Ubuntu 18.04 in dual boot but it is not showing any wifi which is not within a 2 meter range.
It has realtek driver RTL8723BE in it.

```
$ lspci -knn | grep -i net -A3
Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe 
Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:b723] Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [103c:804c] 
Kernel driver in use: rtl8723be 
Kernel modules: rtl8723be
```

In Windows it is showing all networks and connecting as well

In Ubuntu it connects only if the laptop is very close to the router.

I have tried this: [Realtek RTL8723BE Wi-Fi incredibly weak](https://askubuntu.com/questions/883673/realtek-rtl8723be-wi-fi-incredibly-weak) but unfortunately it isn't working

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Add the output of  `lspci -knn | grep -i net -A3`, post  as plain text.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Realtek RTL8723BE Wi-Fi incredibly weak](https://askubuntu.com/questions/883673/realtek-rtl8723be-wi-fi-incredibly-weak)

Comment: have tried it but the above answer is not working in my case