# Weak WI-FI signals on my HP laptop running on Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS with kernel 4.15.0-43-generic

Tags: networking, wireless, 18.04, kernel, realtek-wireless

I have tried all the solutions in the links below but none worked. Before update I was also having the same problem but was managed to solve by changing the antenna setting ant_Sel from 1 to 2  but after updating the ubuntu and rebooting the system ,the WI-FI signal became very weak. It only  works within a range of 2 to 5 meters. It's been more than a day and I am not able to find the correct solution.NO DKMS modules are installed and ant_sel is set to 2 currently

The output of the command:
    lspci -knn | grep -i net -A3

```
01:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.  
  RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 07)   
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller [103c:81eb]   
    Kernel driver in use: r8169   
    Kernel modules: r8169   
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.  
  RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:b723]   
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network  
   Adapter [103c:81c1]   
    Kernel driver in use: rtl8723be   
    Kernel modules: rtl8723be
```

the links used -

[Realtek RTL8723BE Wi-Fi incredibly weak](https://askubuntu.com/questions/883673/realtek-rtl8723be-wi-fi-incredibly-weak)

[Wifi strength extremely weak in ubuntu 18.04.1 with RTL8723BE](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1072372/wifi-strength-extremely-weak-in-ubuntu-18-04-1-with-rtl8723be)

Comment: Please edit the question to include results from terminal for `dkms status; cat /sys/module/rtl8723be/parameters/ant_sel`

Comment: @Jeremy31 ant_sel is currently 2 and and no dkms modules are installed

Comment: Do a search for rtlwifi-new and do a dkms install, make sure Secure Boot is disabled in BIOS.  This is most likely a duplicate question but I don't feel like searching through this to mark it as one

Comment: Did you try `ant_sel=1` ? Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @chili555 yes , i tried ant_sel=1