# Wi-Fi Internal adapter RTL8723BE has weak signal and interference

Tags: wireless, hp, realtek-wireless

I use Ubuntu Studio 18.04.2 LTS in a HP Laptop 250 G5 with Intel Pentium CPU N3710, 4 cores, at 1.6 GHZ, and 8 GB RAM.

It is known that there was (or, maybe still is) a Linux bug with the internal WiFi adapter, which is a Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [103c:81c1] (RealTek 802.11 b/g/n Wireless Adapter).

The main issues were:

1. Bad (weakly) signal gain, and
2. Some kind of "interferences" with the audio and video performance (stuttering).

So I use an external WiFi adapter (USB port).

How can I know if the bug was fixed?

I read the solutions to [Realtek RTL8723BE Wi-Fi incredibly weak](https://askubuntu.com/questions/883673/realtek-rtl8723be-wi-fi-incredibly-weak) I tested it, and they were not effective. The issues are still present!

Comment: Please [edit] and include the exact Realtek model. Your description is common to dozens of different chipsets.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the result of the terminal command: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3`

Comment: I added the data you asked.