# Facing some issue related to wifi connectivity in HP laptop with rtl8723be driver

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, realtek

I googled this issue and got few link one of them is [How do I get a Realtek RTL8723BE wireless card to work? But while following this I gor an error while running

```
sudo apt-get install rtlwifi-new-dkms
**Error message is** 
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 4.15.0-47-generic
(x86_64) Consult /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.10/build/make.log for
more information.
```

I couldn't comment on the same post so asking here.

```
DKMS make.log for rtlwifi-new-0.10 for kernel 4.15.0-47-generic (x86_64)
Sat Apr 20 13:00:43 IST 2019
make: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-47-generic'
Makefile:976: "Cannot use CONFIG_STACK_VALIDATION=y, please install libelf-dev, libelf-devel or elfutils-libelf-devel"
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.10/build/base.o
In file included from /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.10/build/base.c:30:0:
/var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.10/build/wifi.h:1327:40: error: ‘IEEE80211_NUM_BANDS’ undeclared here (not in a function)
  struct ieee80211_supported_band bands[IEEE80211_NUM_BANDS];
                                        ^
/var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.10/build/base.c:138:10: error: ‘IEEE80211_BAND_2GHZ’ undeclared here (not in a function)
  .band = IEEE80211_BAND_2GHZ,
          ^
/var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.10/build/base.c:150:10: error: ‘IEEE80211_BAND_5GHZ’ undeclared here (not in a function)
  .band = IEEE80211_BAND_5GHZ,
          ^
/var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.10/build/base.c: In function ‘_rtl_init_deferred_work’:
/var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.10/build/base.c:517:2: error: implicit declaration of function ‘init_timer’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
  init_timer(&rtlpriv->works.watchdog_timer);
  ^
/var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.10/build/base.c:518:2: error: implicit declaration of function ‘setup_timer’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
  setup_timer(&rtlpriv->works.watchdog_timer,
  ^
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
scripts/Makefile.build:332: recipe for target '/var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.10/build/base.o' failed
make[1]: *** [/var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.10/build/base.o] Error 1
Makefile:1552: recipe for target '_module_/var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.10/build' failed
make: *** [_module_/var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.10/build] Error 2
make: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-47-generic'
```

Above is the log for /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.10/build/make.log

Here is the link of wireless info gathered by following script

```
wget -N -t 5 -T 10 https://github.com/UbuntuForums/wireless-info/raw/master/wireless-info && \chmod +x wireless-info && \./wireless-info
```

https://pastebin.com/8Ctx4pwN

Comment: maybe this will be some help https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2394125

Comment: Not working for me.Everything ran fine but after rebooting not a single  wifi showing

Comment: Please edit the question and include the log for `/var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.10/build/make.log` and please follow the instructions here: https://askubuntu.com/a/425205/167115 and please post a link or the subsequent info in your question, thanks!

Comment: @mchid I have edited the question as you have asked.Please look in and suggest me accordingly.Thank you

Comment: First, run the command: `sudo modprobe rtl8723be ant_sel=1` and if your wifi doesn't work then, try: `sudo modorobe -r rtl8723be` and then `sudo modprobe rtl8723be ant_sel=2` and if either one of these works for you then please see the following post on how to make one of these permanent. According to the post, you don't need the aftermarket firmware (DKMS), you just need to set the antenna to the correct one because the manufacturer of the computer decided to only use one antenna (I have had the same problem with rtl8192ce on a Toshiba). Please let me know if this does work because . . .

Comment: . . . you may need to remove the module from a blacklist as well. Here is the post: https://askubuntu.com/a/883688/167115