# modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'rtl8723be': Required key not available

Tags: wireless, kernel, realtek-wireless

While I was trying to install wifi drivers in ubuntu 18.04, i was getting this error:

```
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'rtl8723be': Required key not available
```

I followed procedure given in [Realtek RTL8723BE Wi-Fi incredibly weak](https://askubuntu.com/questions/883673/realtek-rtl8723be-wi-fi-incredibly-weak)

Unable to figure the reason for the error. Any solution to this problem will be appreciated.